# Animating a 3D car in PyOpenGL

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, graphics, glut, pyopengl

I'm trying to animate a 3D car in PyOpenGL to make it move along an eight-shaped track. The problem is that I don't seem to find the best way to make the car turn along the curve of the track.

The way that I've tried is making the car tranlate over the x and z axis, as well as making a glRotate to rotate the car, but that doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

My code looks like this:

```
 # Values for all the animation process, including translate and rotate
 angulo = 0.0
 traslacion = 0.0
 giroXl = 0.0
 giroZl = 0.0

 ...

 # The display function, where the 3D car model recieves the intructions for 
 # the movement along the track
 def display():
     ...
     glTranslate(0, 0, traslacion)  # Moves the car along a straight line, this works just fine

     # This is where I try to turn the car along the track curve, this is where I'm stuck
     if bandRecta == True:
        glTranslate(giroXl, 0, giroZl)
        glRotate(angulo, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

 # The glutTimerFunc, where the values get manipulated
 def movimiento():
     ...
     angulo = angulo + (1.0 if angulo < 180.0 else 0.0)
     traslacion = traslacion + (1.0 if traslacion < 100.0 else 0.0)

     if traslacion == 50:
          bandRecta = True 
          giroXl = giroXl + (1.0 if giroXl < 50.0 else 0.0)
          giroZl = giroZl + (1.0 if giroZl < 50.0 else 0.0)
```

Can you guys give me some suggestions of how to make the car steering? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this.
(I am not a python programmer so this will not be full syntax.)

### Segments

I guess your track goes R units ahead in the Z direction, then through 3/4 of a circle with radius R.

Make the rotation to be around the point -R,0,R instead of 0,0,0. This involves extra translate() before and after the rotate().

Think of T as the total distance (traslacion) down the track. Don't use T directly in the translate(). Break up the track into segments like this:

```
if (T<=R)
    theta = 0
    Z = T
    X = 0
else if (T < R * (1 + 3/2 * PI))
    theta = (T/R-1)
    Z = R # limit of straight travel
    X = 0
else if (T < R * (3 + 3/2 * PI))
    theta = 3/2 * PI
    Z = R
    X = T - R * (1 + 3/2 * PI)) # now travelling straight in X
else # you work out the other pole of the track
```

Drawing in the first pole of the track:

```
glTranslate(0, 0, Z) # add Z from straight portion of track

# rotate about pole at -R, 0, R
glTranslate(R, 0, -R)
glRotate(180 * theta / PI), 0, 1, 0)
glTranslate(-R, 0, R)

# add X from after the curve
glTranslate(X, 0, 0)
```

That will get you as far as the second turn (which will have a different center).

Note

```
PI = math.pi
```

### Using Parametric Functions

The second way I can think of to approach this is with parametric functions Fx,z (T)

To rotate the car, you need to know the derivative Fx1 and Fz1 and use atan to work out the heading.

If you define

```
Fx = cos(T * K) 
Fz = sin(T * L)
```

you can have a figure eight with K=0.5 and L=1.

But then the math and the drawing is simple:

```
Fx1 = -K * sin(T * K)
Fz1 = L * cos ( T * L)
theta = atan(Fz1/Fx1) if Fx1 != 0 else sign(Fz1)*PI/2
glRotate(180 * theta / PI, 0, 1, 0)
glTranslate(Fx, 0, Fz)
```

Have fun!

Comment: So, based in your answer (of the first way): 
    T = 100
    Z = traslacion
    R = 0 at first, and 
    theta = angulo
f we adapt it to my code?

Comment: @Daniel Corona   radius R= 50 (constant.), theta = angulo (but I use radians not degrees),  T is total track distance and then separated into linear X,Z translations and angular theta.